# Tomcat 6 web app as root - deployed twice?

Tags: tomcat

I have a web app AAA.war, deployed in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps. I want to access it as the root web app.  I modified $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml to add this to the section.

```
<Context path="/" docBase="AAA" reloadable="true" />
```

I can access my app via localhost:8080/, it all works as expected.

But when starting up Tomcat, I see in catalina.out the app deployed twice, and initalised twice. It is accessible also via localhost:8080/AAA - this is not a major problem, but is it normal or does it indicate an underlying problem with my config ?

I am using Tomcat 6.0.26.

Comment: Do you mean place the application in the parent folder of webapps or inside it? Apps are usually placed inside the /webapps/ folder. Also, how do you 'declare' the app in the server.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either place the application in webapps directory, *or* declare it in the server.xml entry.